# about this R warning message

Tags: r, package

When using an R-package, I get the following warning:

```
install.packages("poweRlaw")  
install.packages("devtools")   
library("poweRlaw")  

Warning messages:
1: In installClassMethod(value, self, field, selfEnv, thisClass) :
  method .objectPackage from class conpl was not processed into a class
  method until being installed.  Possible corruption of the methods in the class.  

2: In installClassMethod(value, self, field, selfEnv, thisClass) :
  method .objectParent from class conpl was not processed into a class
  method until being installed.  Possible corruption of the methods in the class.
```

what kind of package I need to install??

Comment: You should post a complete description of your setup. Similar warning messages seem to be affecting other RStudio users: https://bugs.r-project.org/bugzilla3/show_bug.cgi?id=16551